# How to Fix this error http://localhost:8080/assets/Fox.glb 404 (Not Found)

Tags: vue.js, aframe

My webpack settings are not set at all.
I wonder how to solve this error.
I'm currently using Vue.js and A-frame library,
and I'm trying to get a file in the folder `assets`,
but I get the following error. It's not solved for three days. Please help me.

### App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="duck" src="./assets/Fox.glb"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>
      <a-entity gltf-model="url(./assets/Fox.glb)"  timeout="10000"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
   </div>
</template>
```

### My Error

```
GET http://localhost:8080/assets/Fox.glb 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: I think  you should set gltf-model of a-entity to "./assets/Fox.glb" instead of "url(./assets/Fox.glb)"

Comment: Are you sure the model is at `http://localhost:8080/assets/Fox.glb`? is the `assets` folder really in the root path?